# Simple Conditional Formula or Macro

Tags: vba, excel

It sounds simple but I couldn't find a way to do this. I'm fairly limited on VBA.

```
Column A:      
Some Text
Some Text
Some Text
Repeated Text
Some Text
Some Text
Repeated Text
SomeText
```

First colum has some text like this. I also have a list that includes 30 different strings like this:

```
Dog
Cat
Lion
Tiger
Bear
...
Elephant
```

I want to copy paste those strings to Column B with one condition. Whenever that repeated text is encountered at the same row in column A the copied value will change to the next string in the animal list. When it reaches the last animal it should revert back to the first animal "Dog". In the end simply I want something like this;

```
  Column A:          Column B:
R1 Some Text          Dog
R2 Some Text          Dog
R3 Some Text          Dog
R4 Repeated Text      Cat
R5 Some Text          Cat
R6 Some Text          Cat
R7 Repeated Text      Lion
R8 SomeText           Lion
.............
R124 Some Text        Elephant
R125 Some Text        Elephant
R126 Repeated Text    Dog (List is over and it reverted back to the first animal in the list)
R127 Some text        Dog
....
```

I couldn't do it with any excel formula...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple INDEX with A COUNTIF will do the trick.  In B1 put:

```
=INDEX(D:D,MOD(COUNTIF($A$1:$A1,"Repeated Text"),COUNTA(D:D))+1)
```

And copy down.

My list of animals is in Column D.

This will adjust as the list in D gets larger or shorter and will repeat when it reaches the end of the list.

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: Add `MOD()` for looping once the count passes 30 ?

Comment: @TimWilliams fixed it to repeat when the list end is found.  Thanks for the catch.

Comment: At first, It got broken after the third repeated text and starts to move on to next animal seemingly random. I thought it was related to the my repeated  text which was actually "<b>Repeated Text</b>" so I removed the bold tags and formula worked flawlessly. Thanks!

Comment: @LordPermaximum - Ohhh - the data actually has the text "Repeated Text"!!   I thought the question meant column A contained something like A1="abc", A2="def", A3="ghi", A4="ghi" (i.e. a repeat of A3), A5="jkl", etc.  I was going to post an answer that would solve that issue.  It's lucky I didn't.

Answer (score 1):

I like Scott's answer better, but here's my solution:  List of Critters in Column A, some text in C, and the results in D.

```
Sub Get_Animal()
Dim rngAnimals As Range, rngWords As Range, rngThing As Range, strChangeValue As String, AnimalCounter As Long
Set rngWords = ActiveSheet.Range("C1:C26")
Set rngAnimals = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A3")
strChangeValue = "end"
AnimalCounter = 1
ActiveSheet.Range("D1:D99").Clear
For Each rngThing In rngWords
    If rngThing.Text = strChangeValue Then
        AnimalCounter = AnimalCounter + 1
        If AnimalCounter > rngAnimals.Rows.Count Then
            AnimalCounter = 1
        End If
    End If
    rngThing.Offset(0, 1) = rngAnimals.Cells(AnimalCounter, 1)
Next rngThing

End Sub
```